# Firefox renders it wrongly, but achieves the desired effect

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, rendering

Here's the code (http://jsfiddle.net/PZgn8/8/).

```
<ul style="text-align: center;">
    <li>
        <a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Two's child</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm guessing Firefox 21 is rendering it wrong, because iOS Safari (latest version too) renders it like Chrome (desktop, latest version), as well as Chrome for iOS (latest version).

But I want it to look like it does on Firefox 21. How can I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 0):

Safari and Chrome are using the same rendering engine which is Webkit. That's why they display the same result. Firefox is using Gecko.

You should use [css reset](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=css%20reset) codes to get the same effect.

Btw, below code should also give the nearly same effect as Firefox on Chrome:

```
<ul style="margin:0 auto; width:100px">
```